# Jquery album thumbnail with popup gallery

Tags: jquery, popup, gallery, thumbnails

I want to use this plugin but when I put my username and id its not working.
Where I can find alternative like this plugin?
http://code.google.com/p/picasa-popups/

demo :
https://picasaweb.google.com/113476189811132171916/2009_12_gt6

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
    PopulatePicasaGalleries('113476189811132171916', 'links');
    });
</script> 

<div id="links">
    <a href="#" id="id__2009_12_gt6">GT6</a>
</div>
```

my sample not working 
https://picasaweb.google.com/113797508378819391794/GeoPanoramas

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
            PopulatePicasaGalleries('113797508378819391794', 'links');
    });
</script> 
<div id="links">
    <a href="#" id="id__GeoPanoramas">GT6</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Picasa album on your website there is a nice plugin called [PWI](http://code.google.com/p/pwi/)

[Here is an example for PWI Picasa album](http://nccgptc.com/gallery.php)